# Android month view with vertical swipe

Tags: android, android-animation, android-calendar

My requirement is to develop a month view with vertical swipe.

Case -1:

I tried developing this using Directional-Viewpager which is suggested at [Having vertically scrolling pages in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936327/having-vertically-scrolling-pages-in-viewpager) .

I am facing the below issues.

1) Months and Years are not limited and are infinite. We should go for some infinite Cyclic Adapters or we should create illusion to user. How to handle this?

2) Every time the view creation/update functions are not called. Some times cached view is displayed when we traverse back to viewed views and as there is no place to catch this, Am unable to update the Title and data to gridview.

3) Swipe is not working when there are buttons on the gridview.

Case -2:

This is much easy way where i am just applying the Animations to the views. when dragged view down then applying new view animation from top. If dragged UP then new view animation from bottom. As there is no other view below the Gridview, the Animation from bottom is working.
1) The animation of the gridview from the top is coming on the top of the Title which is looking ugly.

2) Swipe is not working when there are buttons on the gridview.

[image: Android Calendar with Gridview]

Can any one look into the issue and suggest me some solution for any one of the above two cases or any custom components or any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the two childrens to a single parent then this issues occurs. Add the children to an another layout and then add this layout to the actual layout. This will resolve your issue.